# zsh history with timestamp slow when piped

Tags: macos, time, zsh

I have set zsh to store 100K lines of history and to save timestamp for every command, and noticed odd behaviour when I try to print history with timestamps.

Running `history -i 1` takes around 2 seconds.
Running `history -i 1 > out` or `history -i 1 > /dev/null` takes around 0.4 second.
But running `history -i 1 | cat` takes around 30 seconds, same for piping through `grep`.

To be sure I checked that [the lines that format and output the time](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/57305cf245853b8b30895b41a90142dffab97e38/Src/builtin.c#L1834-L1838) are responsible, commenting them out makes the piped command run in few seconds, also replacing `localtime` with `gmtime` makes the piped command take only ~15 seconds.
I also tried creating a binary that calls `localtime` 100000 times, but it doesn't take 15 seconds to run.

What can be causing such slowness when piping?

Example output of running `history -iD 1` (`-D` to show duration too):

```
…
100080  2022-03-27 19:33  0:01  history -i 1
100081  2022-03-27 19:33  0:00  history -i 1 > out
100082  2022-03-27 19:33  0:00  rm out
100083  2022-03-27 19:33  0:00  history -i 1 > /dev/null
100084  2022-03-27 19:33  0:30  history -i 1 | cat
100085  2022-03-27 19:34  0:30  history -i 1 | grep history
```

Comment: Could you add example output to your question? Also: why are you even piping through `cat` if the data would anyways be printed to stdout? Third, I'm not sure if that question is a good fit for SO, you might want to ask it on Unix&Linux instead

Comment: @mashuptwice Added example output. I'm using `cat` just as an example for piping and to contrast it with output as is and to file, my main intent is using `grep`. I know that there is `-m` switch for matching, but it is less flexible. This affects me on osx, so I've added macos tag.